# Using Django settings inside a fabric file

Tags: django, fabric

I'd like to iterate through the INSTALLED_APPS in my Django settings file like so:

```
@task
def test_app
    print settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

How do I access my settings file in a fabfile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's documented: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/django.html

```
from fabric.contrib import django

django.settings_module('myproject.settings')
from django.conf import settings
```

Comment: Worth noting: this import your **local** settings, not settings on the remote server.